# In Rails, how can I create new records in a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fields-for

I have a nested form consisting of a parent model, `Challenge`, and a child model `ChallengeRoster`.  In the edit page of a Challenge I can currently edit/update attributes of the Challenge, and can edit/update currently stored ChallengeRoster records.  However, the last step I want is to be able to also select eligible records to create and store in ChallengeRoster by checking a checkbox next to the record shown and then clicking the page's form submit button.  If you look at the `_form.html.erb` file below the issue is with the third loop. Right now I'm able to display the correct `contestant_id` & `challenge_id` for each eligible record to create, but I don't know how to display the checkbox and have the page only add the selected records to the database once I've pressed the form's submit button.  If I've forgotten to post any code please let me know.

***_form.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for @challenge do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
   <%= f.label :description %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :description %>


   <%= f.fields_for :challenge_rosters do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.object.contestant.full_name %><br />
      <%= builder.check_box :active %><br />
      <%= builder.check_box :winner %>
   <% end %>


   <% @roster_options.each do |option| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :challenge_rosters, option do |roster_fields| %>
     <%= roster_fields.object.contestant.full_name %><br />
     <%= roster_fields.text_field :contestant_id %><br />
     <%= roster_fields.text_field :challenge_id %>
     # I want to put a checkbox here to determine which ones I want to add to challenge_rosters table
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

***challenges_controller.rb***

```
def edit

  @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
  @challenge_roster = ChallengeRoster.where(challenge_id: params[:id])

  # I use the next ivar to get contestant_ids that aren't currently part of challenge_rosters, but that are eligible for this challenge
  @options = SeasonRoster.where("season_id = (?) AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM challenge_rosters INNER JOIN challenges ON challenges.id = challenge_rosters.challenge_id WHERE challenge_rosters.contestant_id = season_rosters.contestant_id AND challenges.id = (?))", @challenge.season_id.to_s, @challenge.id.to_s)

  @roster_options = Array.new
  @options.each do |o|
    c = ChallengeRoster.new
    c.contestant_id = o.contestant_id
    c.challenge_id = params[:id]
    @roster_options.push(c)
  end

end
```

***Models***

**challenge.rb**

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :challenge_roster_attributes
  has_many :challenge_rosters
  has_many :contestants, :through => :challenge_rosters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :challenge_rosters, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**challenge_roster.rb**

```
class ChallengeRoster < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :winner, :contestant_id, :challenge_id
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :contestant
end
```

Comment: Not related to your question: (1) instead 'SeasonRoster.where("season_id = " + @challenge.season_id.to_s + "AND...' it is way more preferable to use ? notation: SeasonRoster.where("season_id = (?) AND ...", @challenge.season_id)

Comment: @RoaringStones, thanks! That line of code is one of the things I hate most.  I initially tried to create it with ActiveRecord query notation (not sure if that's actual name for it or if I made that up), but couldn't do it.  I'm not crazy about having SQL in my controller like that as I feel the other way reads much better.

Comment: Please add the private section code of the controller. The part with the white list.

Comment: @wintermeyer, im not sure what you are referring to when you say "white list". Do you mean my "update" method? I don't believe I have a private section.

Comment: The bottom part of your Challenge controller. If you used scaffold it would be the last method.

Comment: @wintermeyer, I believe I used scaffolding -- however, the last thing in the Challenge controller is `def destroy`

Comment: hmmm... so I guess you are not using Rails 4.1. Which Rails version do you use?

Comment: Oh sorry, this app is 3.2.12.

Comment: Could you add a `db/seeds.rb` with some sample data? Plus example `rails generate scaffold Challenge ...` for all models would help. Many people here really like to help but if it takes more than 10 minutes to just figure out the setup it is hard to get any answer. The best chance for a good answer is when you give all the needed data to give people the chance to replay it.